# change the opacity of text only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a navigation bar with sub-menus, on which I put `opacity:.5`(because of other elements that will be positioned underneath). But the text on the sub-menus also got lighter. I want the li to have .5 opacity, and the text in it to have  1 opacity. I tried jquery and I tried css but they don't seem to work. Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e6C74/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `rgba` instead. Replace `opacity: 0.5` inside `ul.submenu` with this

```
background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
```

Also you can remove

```
.submenu span {
    opacity:1;
}
```

You can read more about this property [**here**](http://www.css3.info/introduction-opacity-rgba/)

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e6C74/8/)**

Comment: 10sec quicker very nice... hahah +1 sir

Comment: The problem is that the original background color is taken from it's parent .mainli and for some reason I can't override that.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to use `rgba()` instead of `opacity`

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use rgba instead of hex. This will yield the look you want.

```
   .yourclass{
    background: rgba(248,234,234,0.5); // THe .5 is the opacity.

    }
```

If you are concerned about IE not working try this.

```
 .yourclass {
    background: transparent;-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#7FF8EAEA,endColorstr=#7FF8EAEA)"; /* IE8 */    
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#7FF8EAEA,endColorstr=#7FF8EAEA);   /* IE6 & 7 */      
 zoom: 1;
  }
```

Comment: Just fixed the rgba color fix for IE.

Answer (score 0):

In order to support older browsers you can specify a background colour as normal and also a 50% transparent white png which you remove on :hover

```
li {
  background: #f00 url(image.png);
}
li:hover,
li:active,
li:focus {
  background: #f00;
}
```

Note, this won't work in IE6 unless you use a transparent png polyfil